# SQLite "add column if not exists"

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, conditional-statements

I need to check if a column already exists in a table and add it if not. It is **NOT** possible to check this in the application, because the SQL scripts/files are called successively because of migration. If we add a new column to our database, the column should automatically get added when the app (with a new version) is started.

I have two `SQL Statements`:

#### Add Column `skiptime` into `recipes`

```
ALTER TABLE recipes ADD COLUMN skiptime INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 5;
```

#### Check if the `Column` already exists

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'recipes' AND sql LIKE '%skiptime%'
```

I get a result depending if the `column` exists. Now I want to combine these two statements. But I don't know how.

## Added some code (see comments)

`RunMigrations()` is called one time on the the `Application` startup.

```
ProviderInvariantName
```

can be `SQLite` or `PostgreSQL`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads all resource names from the assembly and saves those containing the db namespace in a private list
/// </summary>
private void _CacheDbRessources()
{
    _RessourcesNamespace = $"FooName.Data.{_ProviderInvariantName}";
    _RessourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().Where(item => item.Contains(_RessourcesNamespace));
}

/// <summary>
/// Does the first-time setup for the database and runs migrations. 
/// </summary>
private void _RunMigrations()
{
    IEnumerable<string> migrations =
        _RessourceNames.Where(item => item.Contains("_Migrations"))
            .Select(s => s.Replace(_RessourcesNamespace + ".", ""))
            .OrderBy(item => item);

    if (migrations.Any())
        _Logger.Debug("Running database migrations...");

    using (DbConnection conn = GetConnection())
    {
        foreach (string item in migrations)
        {
            using (DbTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                _Logger.Debug("Executing query '{0}'...", item);
                using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(GetQueryResource(item), tran))
                {
                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    _Logger.Debug($"{rows} rows where affected.");
                }

                tran.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### 000_InitialCreate.sql (SQLite)

```
/* users */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
    "ident" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "user_name" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "real_name" TEXT,
    "password" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "userlevel" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "enabled" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "language" TEXT,
    "lock" TEXT
);
```

#### 000_InitialCreate.sql (Postgres)

```
/* users */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
    "ident" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_name" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "real_name" TEXT,
    "password" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "userlevel" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "enabled" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "language" TEXT,
    "lock" TEXT
);
```

[image: resources]

Comment: Use program code. Either select first whether the column exists; then when it doesn't invoke alter table, or invoke alter table right away and catch the exception when you get one.

Comment: "It is **NOT** possible to check this in the application"

Comment: This is strange. You are using a programming language where you can execute SQL statements, but you get no response whether that was succesful or not? You can send a query, but you cannot use its result in an if statement? I've never seen such a language, but if you say so, then that's not an option. In SQL you cannot combine the two statements either by the way. So I suggest you switch to another programming language (almost any language would do except for the one you are currently using of course).

Comment: If the (`C#`) application starts, it is looking which database to use (`sqlite`[local], `postgres`[remote]). Then it's executing each *.sql file in the "SQLite/Migrations" or "Postgres/Migrations" folder ordered by a prefixed number. So 1. is an "initalCreate" (no db available;create a new one) and 2. would be (for example) "add a new column" (because of a new software feature; new version) and so on. If any `Exception` is thrown I abort the application startup.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have added some more details..

Comment: This is not possible in SQLite. If your application handled database versions correctly, it would know whether the column exists.

Comment: @CL. and what would be a good strategy to have this migration? If a customer wants `MSSQL` support, It could be possible that I have to expand the `sqlite` and `postgres` `queries` (because of new features)..

Comment: Don't you know from where you migrate? Don't you have some database version?